# obtain request parameter in Spring security Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Can someone help in in obtaining request parameter 
in WebsecurityConfig Httpsecurity configure method ? I need to extract the request parameter in the below case acr=loa3 that is coming from request

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl(this.uiUri + "/expired")
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .and()
            .invalidSessionUrl(this.uiUri + "/expired")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().cors()
            .and()       
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/expired").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
//Can some one help me here on how to extract request param coming in the url for example xyz.com/login?acr=loa3 ? I need to send that as acr value before the configureOIDCfilter executes
            .addFilterBefore(configureOIDCfilter(http, acrValue), 
                             AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(this.redirectUri));
    }
}
@Bean
    public OIDCAuthenticationFilter configureOIDCfilter(HttpSecurity http, String acrValue) throws Exception {

        OIDCAuthenticationFilter filter = new OIDCAuthenticationFilter();
        StaticSingleIssuerService issuerService = new StaticSingleIssuerService();
        issuerService.setIssuer(issuerUrl);
        filter.setServerConfigurationService(new DynamicServerConfigurationService());
        StaticClientConfigurationService clientService = new StaticClientConfigurationService();
        RegisteredClient client = new RegisteredClient();
        client.setClientId(clientId);
        client.setDefaultACRvalues(ImmutableSet.of(acrValue));
        return filter;

    }
```

Comment: The configuration is done at startup time, so there is no URL/request whatsever at the point of configuring the filter.

Answer (score 0):

What you showed in your code is configuration. This is done at startup time and cannot catch any request parameters at this time. However, if you want to need to do something by request, you may want to implement a filter as I wrote in [my recent blog post](https://grobmeier.solutions/spring-security-5-jwt-basic-auth.html).

You could extend from a filter like this:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    public MyAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Then, try to find what methods you want to override. In example:

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
...
}
```

In the above method you can access the http request parameters.

This filter needs to be added to your configuration as well:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilter(new MyAuthenticationFilter()). 
}
```

A filter will be called for any request and is the only way to receive request parameters (to my knowledge).